# Javascript Convert Class Variable to Getter/Setter using Decorators

Tags: javascript, babeljs, ecmascript-next

Any ideas how I can use a decorator to convert a class field into a getter/setter? Example:

```
class Foo:
    @accessor bar = 0;

const foo = new Foo;
```

Should exhibit custom behavior on say, `foo.bar = 1;`

I have already tried something like

```
function accessor(target, name, descriptor) {
    let val;

    return {
        set: function(newVal) {
            val = newVal;
            console.log("setter called");
        },
        get: function() { return val; }
    };
}
```

but this loses the initial value of `bar = 0`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The class requires to maintain private property where the value will be stored.

Since [class fields aren't currently supported](https://github.com/wycats/javascript-decorators/issues/71) by decorators proposal and newer `transform-decorators` Babel plugin, older `transform-decorators-legacy` Babel plugin should be used instead.

As `transform-decorators-legacy` [documentation](https://github.com/loganfsmyth/babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy#best-effort) suggests, in order to provide get/set accessors for a property, `initializer` method and `writable` property should be deleted from descriptor object. Since `initializer` function contains initial class field value, it should be retrieved and assigned to private property:

```
function accessor(classPrototype, prop, descriptor) {
  if (descriptor.initializer)
    classPrototype['_' + prop] = descriptor.initializer();

  delete descriptor.writable;
  delete descriptor.initializer;

  descriptor.get = function () { return this['_' + prop] };
  descriptor.set = function (val) { this['_' + prop] = val };
}

class Foo {
  @accessor bar = 0;
}

const foo = new Foo ;
foo.bar = 1;
```

Due to the way how it works, initial value (`0`) will be assigned to class *prototype* and won't trigger `set` accessor, while next values (`1`) will be assigned to class *instance* and will trigger `set` accessor.

Since `transform-decorators-legacy` isn't spec-compliant, this won't work other decorator implementations, e.g. TypeScript and decorator proposal.

A direct spec-compliant ES6 counterpart for the code above is:

```
class Foo {
  get bar() { return this._bar };
  set bar(val) { this._bar = val };
}

Foo.prototype._bar = 0;
```